# Design pattern for sharing some code with two different classes?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UITableView`. I am using a class inheriting [MGSwipeTableCell](https://github.com/MortimerGoro/MGSwipeTableCell) for my cells and I have a header which is a UIView. I have some portion of code that are pretty similar if it's not exactly the same.

I guess there is a way to write those functions once only and eventually adapt the gap for each class but I don't really know how as the classes are not of the same type.

How could I do it properly?

Comment: Quite vague and can't answer in this state. Quote exact bits of code, and provide enough context: what classes they're members of, what the similar methods are for, and list the full method code. There may be a simple base class / two child classes pattern here but it's impossible to say right now.

Answer (score 0):

Look at protocols and class extensions. You can probably design a protocol the defines the methods you want to share, and then an extension that lets you add methods and properties to your classes.

Comment: but in that case I would still have to implement the methods in each class, wouln't I?